# Sending data between one Thread and two Activities in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I have a `thread` that listens for an `inputStream` and can send some data with some `ouputStream` that I got from a Bluetooth socket.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve: I have a `MainActvity` And `Activity B`. I need to have both to be capable to receive data from the `Thread` or send data to the `Thread`.

I can't just make a new instance of my thread cause it's going to cut the connection.

I'm a new to android and programming so it's very hard to know what I really need.

I tried my best with handlers, Broadcast receiver but had no luck for making it work in `Activity B`.
Whatever may work for my case. It would be nice having an example of it.

Comment: 2 activites? why?

Comment: Maintain your thread in `Service` and call `bindService()` & `unbindService()` in your Activity

Comment: @JoxTraex my application is on android wear. I have two activities because one is for connecting my device to a bluetooth server and the second is to display the some strings with gridviewpager. I cant do that on the MainActivity well as I know. well on the activty B that have the gridview I need also to listen for inputstream and send outputstreams

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) in a Service which runs your Thread and let the Activities register receivers on it.

In your Activity:

```
    final LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("SAMPLE_ACTION");
    lbm.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() called with: context = [" + context + "], intent = [" + intent + "]");
        }
    }, filter);
```

In your Service

```
    final LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    final Intent intent = new Intent("SAMPLE_ACTION");
    lbm.sendBroadcast(intent);
```